# Is there any data to inform a view of the US Nationalization of O&G?

Tags: united-states, oil, gas, nationalization

I was wondering if there was any polling or data historic or otherwise to support a position on the US perspective of nationalizing oil and gas. The majority of the world's reserves are controlled by nationalized companies [with some economists estimating upwards of 90%.](https://consortiumnews.com/2022/04/12/the-case-for-nationalizing-big-oil/) I've seen a lot of data on nationalized health insurance (like NHS), but what is the American perspective on nationalizing the O&G industry and running it like Norway?

Answer (score 2):

> **Question:**
>
> Is there any data to inform a view of the US Nationalization of O&G?

Here is a poll.

**[Nationalize the Fossil Fuel Industry](https://www.dataforprogress.org/blog/4/21/nationalize-the-fossil-fuel-industry)**

Lots of opinions.

- **[Nationalize the U.S. Fossil Fuel Industry to Save the Planet](https://prospect.org/environment/nationalize-us-fossil-fuel-industry-to-save-the-planet/)**
- **[Why we must nationalize Big Oil](https://thehill.com/opinion/energy-environment/3536866-why-we-must-nationalize-big-oil/)**
- **[Commentary: Top Dems Urge Biden To Nationalize Oil & Gas Industry – Michael Shellenberger](https://energynow.com/2022/10/commentary-top-dems-urge-biden-to-nationalize-oil-gas-industry-michael-shellenberger/)**
- **[Nationalize All the Oil Companies](https://jacobin.com/2022/03/nationalize-oil-companies-gas-prices-climate-change-investment-domestic-production)**
- **[Nationalizing Fossil Fuel Industry Is a Practical Solution to Rising Inflation](https://truthout.org/articles/nationalizing-fossil-fuel-industry-is-a-practical-solution-to-rising-inflation/)**
- **[On nationalizing oil](https://dailycampus.com/2022/04/08/on-nationalizing-oil/)**
- **[A Moderate Proposal: Nationalize the Fossil Fuel Industry](https://newrepublic.com/article/156941/moderate-proposal-nationalize-fossil-fuel-industry)**
- **[Out of Time: The case for nationalizing the fossil fuel industry](https://thenextsystem.org/learn/stories/out-time-case-nationalizing-fossil-fuel-industry)**

In my opinion will never happen.  Americans in general prefer market driven solutions.  When corporations become more powerful than the markets American's prefer to reform the market and reintroduce competition over nationalization as was done to **[Standard Oil in 1911](https://guides.loc.gov/chronicling-america-standard-oil-monopoly)** through the **[Sherman anti trust laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman_Antitrust_Act)**.

Outside of war time WWI, WWII and Korea, I can't remember any Nationalizations of industry other than Amtrak in 1971 and that take over was mostly voluntary.  Maybe airport security after 9/11 but that doesn't really fit either.

In general American's prefer and or got stuck with a government designed to move slowly require a lot of consensus and deliberation.  This is because the founding fathers all revolutionaries were concerned with the power of government.

Businesses especially those important for the economy require more nimble market driven solutions most Americans would say are outside their governments competence.

If their is one way to make the oil industry unprofitable it's to put it under government control.

Comment: i don't see any of these articles citing an opinion poll or the like about the popularity of the option, that's what i'm looking for. You state "Americans in general prefer market driven solutions." but you have no evidence that it is preferred here in this application. This may just be a lack of data, but in health care for instance you can specify 55% of voters support Medicare for All, and 68% of voters support a public health insurance option https://pro.morningconsult.com/articles/medicare-for-all-public-option-polling